# How to combine two or more DataTables dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable, clone, resultset

I have two DataTables being filled.

```
DT1 and DT2
```

Each DataTable has the same column headers. However, DT2 may or may not have the same amount of rows.

```
ID | Type | Value
```

I need the new Table to add Rows as necessary based on the number of results that are returned in the "Type" column and set DT3 rows ID = DT1.ID and Value to "N/A"

```
       DT1                        DT2                             DT3
ID | Type   | Value        ID | Type   | Value        ID | Type   | Value
1   ItemCost   5000        27  ItemCost   3800        27  ItemCost   3800
2   TravCost   5700        28  TravCost   4851        28  TravCost   4851
3   UpCharge   3600                                   3   UpCharge   N/A
4   TaxCost    7000                                   4   TaxCost    N/A
```

Comment: I basically need something like a vlookup. But instead of doing it with the tables I need to do it with the result-set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my code for this issue:

```
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("ID");
            dt1.Columns.Add("Type");
            dt1.Columns.Add("Value");
            dt1.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "1", "ItemCost", "5000" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "2", "TravCost", "5700" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "3", "UpCharge", "3600" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "4", "TaxCost", "7000" });
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("ID");
            dt2.Columns.Add("Type");
            dt2.Columns.Add("Value");
            dt2.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "27", "ItemCost", "3800" });
            dt2.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "28", "TravCost", "4851" });
            DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
            dt3 = dt2.Clone();
            foreach (DataRow item in dt2.Rows)
            {
                dt3.Rows.Add(new object[] { item["ID"], item["Type"], item["Value"] });
            }
            foreach (DataRow item in dt1.Rows)
            {
                DataRow[] drs = dt3.Select("Type='" + item["Type"].ToString() + "'");
                if (drs.Count() == 0)
                {
                    dt3.Rows.Add(new object[] { item["ID"], item["Type"], "N/A" });
                }
            }
```

Comment: Yes it is very close to working but one more thing. How do I convert the value type? Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <N/A> in Value Column.  Expected type is Double. Thanks iceDragon

Comment: Thanks for the help iceDragon. I ended up just adding this: CONVERT (VARCHAR(50),Value) AS Value to the original query statements for each DataTable. Thanks again for the help